# avoid partitions unbalancing Spark

Tags: apache-spark, rdd, shuffle, hadoop-partitioning

I have a **performance problem** with a code I'm revisioning, everytime will give an `OOM` while performing a count.
I think I found the problem, basically after `keyBy` tranformation, being executed `aggregateByKey.`
The problem lies to the fact that almost 98% of the RDD elements has the same key, so aggregationByKey, generate shuffle, **putting nearly all records into the same partition**, bottom line: just few executors works, and has to much memory pressure.

This is the code:

```
val rddAnomaliesByProcess : RDD[AnomalyPO] = rddAnomalies
    .keyBy(po => po.getProcessCreator.name)
    .aggregateByKey(List[AnomalyPO]())((list,value) => value +: list,_++_)
    .map {case(name,list) =>
      val groupByKeys = list.groupBy(po => (po.getPodId, po.getAnomalyCode, po.getAnomalyReason, po.getAnomalyDate, po.getMeasureUUID))
      val lastOfGroupByKeys = groupByKeys.map{po => (po._1, List(po._2.sortBy { po => po.getProcessDate.getMillis }.last))}
      lastOfGroupByKeys.flatMap(f => f._2)
    }
    .flatMap(f => f)

log.info("not duplicated Anomalies: " + rddAnomaliesByProcess.count)
```

I would a way to perform operation in a more parallel way, allowing all executors to work nearly equally. How can I do that?

**Should I have to use a custom partitioner?**

Comment: *"The problem lies to the fact that almost 98% of the RDD elements has the same key"* Is there a reason so many elements have the same key? Is that a business requirement?

Comment: Actually I don't know, I don't have any functional knowledge, I'm just trying to find performance bottleneck. I must consider that they had thought about it and partitioning is right.

Comment: Perhaps if the key generation was better, and ideally uniform, you wouldn't have a problem where a single partition was so large.

Comment: But as you can see, they do also an aggregateByKey, so I should trying to solve without changing code, other than partioning transformations.

Comment: Yes , is a very bad piece of code, no doubt about it. I would like Just ti know if there was any quick and dirty solution applicable without changing program Logic and I was thinking if partitioning could solve or at least alleviate performance problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your observation is correct and

> 98% of the RDD elements has the same key

then change of partitioner won't help you at all. By the definition of the partitioner 98% of the data will have to be processed by a single executor.

Luckily bad code is probably the bigger problem here than the skew. Skipping over:

```scala
.aggregateByKey(List[AnomalyPO]())((list,value) => value +: list,_++_)
```

which is just a folk magic it looks like the whole pipeline can be rewritten as a simple `reuceByKey`. Pseudocode:

- Combine `name` and local keys into a single key:

  ```scala
  def key(po: AnomalyPO) = (
    // "major" key
    po.getProcessCreator.name, 
    // "minor" key
    po.getPodId, po.getAnomalyCode,
    po.getAnomalyReason, po.getAnomalyDate, po.getMeasureUUID
  )
  ```

  Key containing name, date and additional fields should have much higher cardinality than the name alone.
- Map to pairs and reduce by key:

  ```scala
  rddAnomalies
    .map(po => (key(po), po))
    .reduceByKey((x, y) => 
      if(x.getProcessDate.getMillis > y.getProcessDate.getMillis) x else y
    )
  ```